# To send Push Notification through firebase from 2 different Backend application, Do we require separate Server Key from firebase Console?

Tags: firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, key, .net-6.0

I have 2 backend UAT application hosted on 2 different environment independent from each other (Different Domain), and I have a one common front end application.
To send push notification from both the Backend application separately.
Do I require separate server keys, which we create from the Firebase console for the 2 backend application?
Because currently I am getting error while sending push notification from newly created backend environment.
From my exisiting backend environment I am able to send push Notification.
Backend application is in **c# .Net 6 Core**

I checked the code, There are no code level changes in the New & Existing backend application.
I have doubt related to the Server Key, Do I need to create new server key or I can use same for both backend applications.

Comment: I think you should start by giving it a try, then post if you have specific code with an error that doesn't work the way you expect

Answer (score 1):

> To send Push Notification through firebase from 2 different Backend application, Do we require separate Server Key from firebase Console?

Nope. Multiple backends can use the same server key to send messages through FCM.

Comment: Okay, Thanks I will check this at my end